# Terraform State file

Tags: terraform

I have 2 different version of terraform state files.

- terraform v0.11 holds all the info of the resources which was created using version v0.11
- terraform v0.12 holds new resources being created with terraform version v0.12

Now how can I merge v0.11 state file to v0.12 version terraform state file so all the info of version 0.11 merged into new version file v0.12

Nothing has been tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly. Instead, you have to [import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import) resources that you have in TF v0.11 into v0.12. This is a manual process, done for each resource separately.

Comment: Do I need to use terraform mv (move) command or Import.

Comment: @user3540063 As I wrote, you have to use `import`.